# How to call a child (powershell) runbook inline from a parent (powershell) runbook in Azure automation?

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

In an attempt to create some reusable powershell code I am trying to get the inline invocation of a child runbook to work. I am relatively new to PowerShell and to Azure Automation.

All the attempts I made so far to make an inline call from a parent workbook to a child runbook fail with the following error:

**The term './*<name_of_child_runbook>*.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Both runbooks are *PowerShell* (version 7.1). Both runbooks reside under the same Automation account.

For sake of clarity, I tried to bring it down to its simplest form. Here is the content of the **child runbook**, named ***rnbk_test_child***.

```
Write-Output "Hello, this is the child runbook."
```

The **parent runbook** also has one single line of code and looks like this:

```
./rnbk_test_child.ps1
```

I first published the child runbook before creating and testing the parent runbook. I mainly worked from the information in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks#invoking-a-child-runbook-using-inline-execution).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the child runbook using the Az cmdlet `Start-AzAutomationRunbook` from the `Az.Automation` module.

```
$automationAccountName = '<InsertHere>'
$runbookName = '<InsertHere>'
$automationAccountResourceGroup = '<InsertHere>'

$startAutomationRunBookSplat = @{
        AutomationAccountName = $automationAccountName 
        Name                  = $runbookName
        ResourceGroupName     = $automationAccountResourceGroup 
        Parameters            = $ParametersHashtable
    }
    
    Start-AzAutomationRunbook @startAutomationRunBookSplat -verbose
```

Docs on the usage here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/start-azautomationrunbook?view=azps-7.4.0

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for replying. I am aware about this cmdlet, but for this particular question I would like to get the inline call to work (or understand why it is not) rather than going around the issue by using the cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you have already figured this out but as far as I'm aware all you need to do in the parent runbook is call the child runbook as if it was a inline powershell function

e.g

```
runbktestchild -parameter1 "value"
```

I dont think it will work if the runbook name has underscores in it :S

Comment: Hi @Julian! Thanks for your reply. It has been a while since I was working on this one, but no I don't recall we really got it to work. But your reaction makes me wonder if we ever tried it without the underscores. Good point! Will have to check that out. tx!